# Should I type something as Optional if None breaks the logic of the function, but I do check for it inside the body?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

Sometimes at the beginning of my Python functions I check whether the correct variables types were used, or whether something was passed as `None`. For example:

```py
def fails_with_none(x: int):
  if x is None:
    raise TypeError('Function fails with None!')
  return x + 1
```

I am hesitating whether `x` should be typed as `int` or as `Optional[int]`.
The reason for using just `int` is that, semantically, the function requires an `int`.
However, if I think about this from a programming perspective, the function handles both integer and `None` inputs.

Is there a recommended way?

For example, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51710151/2982614) the `Optional` hint means "either an object of the specific type is required, or `None` is required".

However, the question still remains: Required by what? If we take it to mean "required by the logic of the function", then it should be typed as `int`. If we take it to mean "required by the code being executed", then since we check whether `x is None`, it should be included as a possible type hint.

Comment: the way you defined your function, `x` is not optional, and calling your function with 0 parameters will throw an error. If you want to make the parameter optional, assign a default value to it.

Comment: `Optional` hints that the argument accepts `None` as a value. It's the same as `x: int | None` (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional)). Note that it is not the same as an optional parameter (for which you provide a default)

Comment: To somewhat correct the two comments above: `Optional` does not mean that an argument may be omitted. It means that the value being passed may be `None`. The *default parameter value* is what decides if the value needs to be passed. If the default parameter value is `None`, then the correct type would be `Optional[int]`, since the parameter may be `None` or an `int`.

Comment: Thank you @EDG956.
Looking at the docs that you linked, it says _"On the other hand, if an explicit value of None is allowed, the use of Optional is appropriate"_
I guess my question would be: in my example it seems to me that an explicit value of None is allowed, because the function takes care of it by raising an exception. On the other hand, other may argue that an explicit value of None is not allowed, because it breaks the logic of the function. 
Which interpretation is the correct one?

Comment: by raising a `TypeError` when `x is None`, you're doing the same as a type checker would with the type hint `x: int`. This means `None` is not a valid argument type and you should not mark it as `Optional`

Comment: I see, thank you again. Would things change if I raised a different exception type?

Comment: In actual practice, Python itself does not currently enforce the type hints, so doing the work twice may be called for as an interim solution. On the other hand, I believe there are optional modules which _will_ turn type mismatches into fatal errors; maybe try one of those. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63838471/possible-to-enforce-type-hints

Comment: @EDG956 could you write out an answer? I would be happy to accept it! Thank you!

Comment: @tripleee It doesn't _"currently not enforce type hints"_, it is **designed** to be dynamically typed. There is nothing "interim" about this. That is the paradigm. Type hints are extremely useful and I can't think of an example, when you should _not_ use them. But _enforcing_ them goes against the entire philosophy of Python and I see no reason to expect that to change at _any time_.

Comment: Depends on how useful it is to fail early. `None + 1` already raises a `TypeError` with (IMO) a sufficiently descriptive error message, and if the cost of doing an explicit check is really worth relieving the caller of the "need" to use a tool like `mypy`.

Comment: Thanks @Sharkovsky87, but I see that others have provided more deserving answers already. Please go ahead and accept one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**: If `x` being `None` has meaning in your function, then annotate `x` accordingly. Otherwise don't and don't check it.

---

> Sometimes at the beginning of my python functions I check whether the correct variables types were used, or whether something was passed as `None`.

I am not saying this is absolutely wrong, but there is no doubt that this goes hardcore against the philosophy of Python.

A main pillar of the paradigm of the language is dynamic typing. This is also why type annotations in Python are commonly referred to as **hints**. This is to signal that the language has no built in mechanism for enforcing this **and** that by convention functions do not *force* type conformity on users.

The contract is this:

*"Hey user, my function `f` accepts an argument of type `int`. That is how I designed it. You may try and use it differently, but at your own peril. I don't vouch for it working as intended, if you pass anything other than `int` to it."*

If you **insist** on enforcing types, then the only consistent way IMHO is to do a negative check against the type you annotated with. If you have `f(x: int)`, then it would be consistent to check like this:

```py
def f(x: int) -> None:
    if not isinstance(x, int):
        raise TypeError
    print(x**2)
```

Because the alternative is arbitrarily checking against any other type that `x` might also be. Specifically, why would you check for it being `None`? Why not also check against it being a `str`? Or an empty `tuple`? Or literally anything else?

Since you provided no additional context, I have to assume from your example that `None` has no special semantic meaning in your function other than that it triggers the `TypeError`.

---

> I am hesitating whether `x` should be typed as `int` or as `Optional[int]`. The reason for using just `int` is that, semantically, the function requires an `int`.

There is your answer then. Semantics is king. If `None` has *no other meaning* in your function, then you should completely ignore its existence. It's up to the user of the function to adhere to your type annotations or disregard them at his own peril.

In this concrete case, this would not even be particularly useful because the default built-in Python error for misusing numeric operands is this:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

So you don't even change the error type, just the message in this particular case.

---

Don't get me wrong, there are obviously cases, where passing `None` as an argument is meaningful. If an argument being `None` has meaning in a function, then obviously you should type it accordingly. Here is a crude example:

```py
def f(x: int | None) -> None:
    if x is None:
        print("Ok then.")
    else:
        print(f"{x**2=}")
```

In this case the function behaves differently depending on whether you pass it an `int` or a `NoneType`. Thus, a union of those is the proper type annotation for `x`. And `Optional[int]` is just a (arguably poorly named) equivalent of that union.

---

Thus, to me, your question title is a non-starter:

> Should I type something as `Optional` if `None` breaks the logic of the function, but I do check for it inside the body?

If you check for `None`, then `None` **does not** break the logic of your function; it is specifically part of the logic and thus should be accounted for in the parameter type annotation.

The bigger question (as I laid out above) is, whether you **should** check for it. If you only check, so you can yell at the programmer in your own customized way for using `None`, I don't see the value in that.

Answer (score 5):

Precisely *because* the type hint won't stop `None` from being passed at runtime is why you should use `int` instead of `Optional[int]`.

Using `Optional[int]` prevents someone who uses `mypy` from catching what should be a static type error, while using `int` won't affect anyone *not* using a static type checker anyway.

`int` both documents your intent *and* provides the ability to catch the error prior to running your code.

---

Once you do that, it is my opinion that you should drop the explicit instance check. If the check fails, that means the caller has already ignored the documentation and potentially a static type checker and passed `None` as an argument anyway. At this point, it's really not your job to protect them from the consequences of `None + 1` anymore.